# Mail validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to use laravel form validation.

My validation code is:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
  'name' => 'required|alpha_num|max:255',
  'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
  'register_no' => 'required|regex:/(1)[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}/',
  'password' => 'required|min:6'
]);
```

`name` takes everything whereas I want only letters & hyphen(-).
`email` takes `gt@hj.fhdfygt@hj.fhdfy` whereas I want like `something@anything.com`.
`register_no` says pattern doesn't match I wrote to return like `111-111-001`.

Comment: There already is an [email validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-email) in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

instead of alpha_num you can use regex (regular expression rule) for your custom formate like:

```
'name'     => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
```

the above is for alphabet without spaces you can create your own

Answer (score 0):

u can use alpha_dash instead of alpha_num for name.